# How do i StartPosition of the form from the current mouse cursor position?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this line:

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

In my program each time i click on a button its showing the new form.
But its not good i want that the form position to be each time where the mouse cursor is.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this at form_Load() event

```
var _point = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
Top = _point.Y;
Left = _point.X;
```

Comment: What do i do with Top and Left ? Using them with: this.Location... ?

Comment: `Top` and `Left` are form properties and it is the same with `this.Top` and `this.Left`

Comment: I am curious is there any specific reason to create `Point` first and not assigning `Cursort.Position.X` to `this.Left` directly?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with constructor overloads, but otherwise it is the same as John Woo answer.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // mandatory, could be set in the designer
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
}

public Form1(int x, int y):
    this()
{
    this.Left = x;
    this.Top = y;
}

public Form1(Point location):
    this()
{
    this.Location = location;
}
```

and use it from *another form* event (because of `this` to set parent):

```
var form = new Form1(Cursor.Position);
form.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var form = new Form1();
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        form.Left = Cursor.Position.X;
        form.Top = Cursor.Position.Y;

        var width= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        var height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

        if (form.Left + form.Width > width)
        {
            form.Left = width - form.Width;
        }

        if (form.Top+form.Height>height)
        {
            form.Top = height - form.Height;
        }
```